# grunt-usemin: ignore a script within build block

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I have a bunch of scripts that I want to run some tasks on (concat, minify) which I have defined in a block:

```
<!-- build:js js/app.js -->
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app-dev.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/components/inputForm/inputFormControllers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/components/inputForm/inputForm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

I want to ignore a file within this block ("js/app-dev.js") - which is used to bootstrap the app with development configurations - when the app is built. Does usemin support a nested statement to ignore individual files within the block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cejast, usemin does not support this kind of feature now. This feature will only be available after a rewrite of the parse to switch from regexp to HTML parsing. I'm currently working on it but it won't be available soon.

Another option might be to configure `useminPrepare` to ignore `-dev.js` file and it might works for you.

Comment: Any word on this? I have a similar problem... Also, I didn't find any documentation on how to configure `useminPrepare` to ignore files...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible for you to put app-dev.js into a separate build block, you might try just leaving out the reference to the file it is supposed to go to for that block.  When I tried this, I got it to successfully build my new index file without a reference to the undesired script while the others built as expected in their own block.

```
<!-- build:js js/app.js -->
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/components/inputForm/inputFormControllers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/components/inputForm/inputForm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js -->
    <script src="js/app-dev.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

My output was something along these lines when I tried something similar:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script> //Without js/app-dev.js
```

Comment: What I need to do in case I want to skip file from concat and uglify but want that in dist file